# How to ask basic statistical analysis questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, fundamentals

I am very new to statistical analysis and so I have a feeling that a lot of what is going to be discussed here will be over my head. Just graduating from college, I'd really like to continue learning by diving deeper into this subject. But I know I am lacking the fundamentals.

How, or when, should I post questions here about something I don't know? After doing some quick Googling on some of the initial questions, I found that there weren't many "plain english" explanation of terms or concepts.

I want to learn about this stuff and I'm sure plenty of other n00bs want to as well. Do you guys/gals have some suggestions on when the right time to ask a question on statexchange is and when it is better to go off and research by yourself?

Comment: One such example of a question in question is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222/what-are-principal-component-scores

Answer (score 5):

My two different suggestions.

1. Fundamental questions are
   going to be asked anyway (in fact,
   they already are; e.g., [standard
   deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-standard-deviation), [p & t values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests),
   [normality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-normality)), so ask away.  If
   the answers don't meet your need,
   try to clarify what you don't understand or how the answers could be more helpful to you.  The submitted
   answers should get better as more
   people have a chance to chime in. 
   If they reach a level that the
   community deems "good enough" they
   can become canonical.
2. I would
   suggest that you check the obvious
   places (e.g.,
   [simple.wikipedia.org/](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Statistics),
   [wikiversity.org](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Category:Statistics)).  You're bound
   to still have questions, even after
   going over those resources, and
   those subsequent questions would
   probably be perfect to ask here. In conjunction with this, if you have references you would recommend users check first, please add them as an answer to [What resources should I review before I ask a basic question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-resources-should-i-review-before-i-ask-a-basic-question)

Comment: +1 I would like to emphasize the following two points from the above answer: 1. Search elsewhere (wiki, google) first. 2. Digest the material that you find and ask questions reg the topic that you still do not understand.

Comment: I agree, both with the above answer and Srikant.  To emphasize: when people know that you've put in some effort, they're much more likely to put in theirs.

Comment: While I agree with the overall content of this answer I have to disagree strongly about the suggestion of "simple wiki". If this was suggested to a question of mine I would probably get offended. While I might not be a native speaker I am pretty confident in my english, and most of problems with statistics articles on wikipedia are due to plain bad formulation rather than complexity of the english used.. Anyways that's my two cents.