# What resources should I review before I ask a basic question?

Tags: support, fundamentals

In conjunction with [a possible FAQ](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain/82#82), I'm adding this as a CW to collect resources that users with basic questions can refer to prior to posting questions.

What are references that you have found personally useful, or have recommended to others, to learn statistics?  Please include either a url or a full citation.

Answer (score 5):

The Wikitrilogy: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStatistics), [Simple Wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStatistics), and [Wikiversity](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Category%3aStatistics)

Comment: Cool, didn't know about Wikiversity. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Wikipedia is a big one -- to fulfill the requirements relating to search and research, for many basic questions a read of the relevant wikipedia page before posting is a no-brainer. If a question can be answered by quoting the first few sentences of the relevant wikipedia page you have to wonder if any research was done at all.

Answer (score 4):

It's also worth trying [**google**](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=google).

Comment: You should hyperlink that so everyone knows how to get there.

Comment: The point of the website is to have questions answered without the need to spend hours searching for a solution. Any question (or 99% of them) can be answered with research. OK, some answers can be found in less than a minute, but even then, the answer might not be at a level the person can follow, or in other cases the topic might benefit from discussion. It would be good not to start turning down legitimate questions just because the answer can be found somewhere. I got a reply pointing me to a google scholar search with lots of academic papers that are very technical. That isn't the point.

Comment: @Vivi: A questioner should put a minimal amount of effort into asking a question.  I think that it's reasonable to do a little background work in order to formulate a good question.